# where is DNS in administrative tools on windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

As I read here
https://store.opendns.com/setup/operatingsystem/windows-2008s

Change your settings: Configuration for Server 2008
From the Start menu, select Administrative Tools, then select DNS.

But I can't see DNS ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `Import-Module Servermanager` then `Get-WindowsFeature` from Powershell to find out if the DNS server role is installed.  It will give you a visual list of all Roles/ Features and what is and isn't installed.  If it is not you can install it from the Server Manager Roles menu, using the Add New Roles Wizard. Or you can use Powershell to install it:

```
Add-windowsFeature DNS
```

Also, if DNS WAS installed on your server, the DNS console would show up in the Admin Tools folder where you are looking.

Answer (score 5):

The DNS management tools are an optional component, and can be installed without installing the DNS Server components.

> Server Manager | Features | Add Feature | Remote Server Administration Tools | Role Administration Tools

and select DNS Server.

Comment: Richard's solution worked for me to install the remote admin tools without having to install the server role.